# MySQL: Load Data Infile from CSV that consist of comma in VARCHAR field

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

Below is the code that I use to import CSV file to MySQL database. It works well to divide all the field and its record.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE customer FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(
    ID, name, salary, address, status
);
```

However, when there is a VARCHAR or TEXT field which consist of comma (','), it works improperly. It is because I use FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' that used to separate each field record.

So, for example, if a customer with salary 50,000 (double), it split the field normally. But, if the customer address is Java Road 15, Hong Kong (varchar/text), Java Road 15 will be saved in address field, while the Hong Kong will be saved to status field. This basically remove any record inside the status field. Any clue for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data would help. I guess commas in text-fields have to be escaped...

Comment: Are the elements in the CSV file that contain commas quoted? If so,you should specify the quote character.

Comment: I just want to change the Fields Terminated by other delimiter, but it shows an error. What should I write in my code if I want to change the delimiter to ^?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are the fields enclosed by double quotes or something else?  If so, you can add the "ENCLOSED BY" in your query.

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

"Enclosed by" specifies the character to identify the start and end of a field.  In your case, field is enclosed by a double quote such as "Java Road 15, Hong Kong". It helps MYSQL to extract the field correctly even if there is a field delimiter in the field.

MYSQL manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Nope, the problematic field is actually a comment for customer, for example Direct Transaction, Cash. The comma between Direct Transaction and Cash split this comment into the next field.

Comment: Wait, it works with enclosed, I don't know why. Can u explain me how enclosed by works? I want to understand it

Comment: Updated answer with explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eddie.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' 
INTO TABLE customer FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(
    ID, name, salary, address, status
);
```

Try this one.

Comment: Yes, it works, same like above solution. It needs the enclosed by. Can you explain me what is the function of enclosed by actually?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone happens to stumble upon this answer, I wanted to share b/c this took me way too long to figure out - using mac, datagrip, mysql 5.7+, survey response questions:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS surveyQuestion_ID;
#create table
CREATE TABLE surveyQuestion_ID
(
  surveyQuestion_ID INT(11) NOT NULL,
  surveyDescription TEXT,
  surveyResponse    VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (surveyQuestion_ID)
);
#load query
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file_location/file.csv' INTO TABLE surveyQuestion_ID
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(surveyQuestion_ID, surveyDescription,  surveyResponse);
```

Hope this helps.